# how to read nested objects(object inside object) in lua file

Tags: lua, kong

I am writing lua file. In that we have to read the requested body. Below is the sample request body json.

```json
{
"year":"2023",
"languageId":"2",
"city":"Banglore",
"TheatreInfo": [
{
"tId":"123",
"tname":"inox"
},
{
"tId":"124",
"tname":"inox"
}
],
"usecase":"tdetails"
}
```

i tried to read above json in lua file like below.

```
local transform_body = {}
transform_body["year"]=body["year"]
transorm_vody["languageid"]=body["languageId"]
transorm_vody["city"]=body["city"]
```

but how to read for theatreinfo nested object.and theatreinfo may contains one or more entries.

Comment: `body.TheatreInfo[1].tId`

Comment: It's not different from how you read any other table. https://www.lua.org/pil/2.5.html
`body["TheatreInfo"]`, or short `body.TheatreInfo`, just gives you another table, which you can again index.

Comment: @luke100000, sorry I didn't get exactly. How to iterate and assign to transform_body.

Comment: @luke100000, directly we can assign, is there no iteration required to assign to transform_body[siminfo]. Please suggest?

Comment: If you know that you only have one theatreinfo, then there is no need for iteration and ESkris answer is what you want. If not, read this and the next page: https://www.lua.org/pil/4.3.4.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use any json to lua library, for example
https://github.com/rxi/json.lua

```
json = require "json"
local tabl = json.decode('[1,2,3,{"x":10}]') -- Returns { 1, 2, 3, { x = 10 } }
```