# How to read/iterate Array of ojects in lua script

Tags: arrays, object, lua

I am writing lua file. In that we have to read Array of objects to the requested body. Below is the sample request body json.

```
{ 
"year":"2023",
 "languageId":"2",
 "city:"Banglore", 
"TheatreInfo": [ 
    { "tId":"123", "tname":"inox" },
    { "tId":"124", "tname":"inox" } 
  ],
 "usecase":"tdetails" 
}
```

We tried to read above json in lua file like below.

```
local transform_body = {};
transform_body["year"]=body["year"]; 
transform_body["languageid"]=body["languageId"]; 
transform_body["city"]=body["city"];
```

How do I write a lua script for Array of objects TheatreInfo?

Comment: Your question has been asked and answered already: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77634753/how-to-read-nested-objectsobject-inside-object-in-lua-file

Answer (score 0):

First I think you could have just assigned the body to transform_body = {}. that way you do not need to do any manipulation.

But in an event you needed to manipulate the data that is returned from the request body. Here are couple of options.

Lets say you want to flatten your data to be Tid | Year | Language Id | City | TName

Then I will write that like this.

```
local transform_body = function ( body )
   local theatreInformation = {};
   local theatreInfo = body["TheatreInfo"];
   if theatreInfo then
      local information  =  {
                    tid = theatreInfo.tId,
                    tname = theatreInfo.tname
                    year = body.year, 
                    languageid = body.languageId,
                    city = body.city 
            };
        table.insert( threatreInformation, information );
     end
  return theatreInformation;
end

local bodyData = transform_body( body );
```

This will transform your data into the format below

***tid | tname | year | languageid | city***

123 | inox | 2023 | 2 | Banglore

124 | inox | 2023 | 2 |Banglore